# Java- Input integer number n and print out whether it has 3 at hundred column or not

Tags: java

If the user enters a number which has 3 in the hundreds column I want to print yes, if not I want to print no, eg:

> 1**3**78
>
> 4**3**56
>
> 10**3**00
>
> **3**50

Should all result in 'yes' being printed

> 100
>
> 1234
>
> 10134

Should all result in no being printed

Here is my code so far:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
String str = String.valueOf(n);
char[] c = str.toCharArray();
if (c[c.length-3] == '3') { 
    System.out.println("yes");
} else { 
    System.out.println("no");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I’d use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` for input, `Integer.parseInt()` to check if I got an integer (catch `NumberFormatException`) and `String.charAt(String.length() - 3)` to inspect the char at the hundreds column. Anything more you need?

Comment: First of all, show your code your tried

Comment: Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        
       String str = String.valueOf(n);
       char[] c = str.toCharArray();
       
           if (c[c.length-3] == '3') {
               System.out.println("yes");
           } else {
               System.out.println("no");
           }
This is my code, is this true?

Comment: Nice. Seems you’re done, arent’t you? Please remember to mark correct/helpful answers as such. If it were me, I’d avoid the call to `toCharArray` and use `str.charAt(...)`, but either works, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public boolean HasThree(Integer n) {
    int a = n / 100;
    int b = a % 10;
    return (b == 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean lookFor3(int input) {
    int reduce = input/100;
    int onlyHundred = reduce % 10;
    return onlyHundred == 3;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. make it a String
2. do toCharArray
3. see if size >= 3
4. if arr[arr.length-3] == '3'

Comment: shouldn´t it rather be `arr[arr.length-3]` that you have to check for the hundreds value?

Comment: This wont work if the number is for example 132304, because then it would check if 2304 starts with a '3', which is not a hundred number.

Comment: The nice thing is if you fix the bug in which char to inspect, it will work for negative numbers too.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did it :D

Comment: but does anyone has idea for doing this by using only loops, if...else and arithmetic operators ?

Comment: Why would you want to use a loop?? Would that be to repeat the whole thing with a new input? Go ahead, you can do that. And you already have an if statement in your code. Some of the other replies show the use of arithmetic operators / and % (only remember that the last remainder may be -3 if you started out from a negative input).

Comment: it's just exercise requirement and I can do it too. Thanks for your help :)